# How can we do operations inside indexing operations in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, indexing, operation

For example, let's imagine following vector in R:

```
a <- 1:8; k <- 2
```

What I would like to do is getting for example all elements between 2k and 3k, namely:

```
interesting_elements <- a[2k:3k]
Erreur : unexpected symbol in "test[2k"
interesting_elements <- a[(2k):(3k)]
Erreur : unexpected symbol in "test[2k"
```

Unfortunately, indexing vectors in such a way in R does not work, and the only way I can do such an operation seems to create a specific variable k' storing result of 2k, and another k'' storing result of 3k.

Is there another way, without creating each time a new variable, for doing operations when indexing?

Comment: This has nothing to do with indexing. It’s just how R syntax for arithmetic works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R does not interpret `2k` as scalar multiplication as with other languages. You need to use explicit [arithmetic operators](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Arithmetic).

If you are trying to access the `4` to `6` elements of `a` then you need to use `*` *and* parentheses:

```
a[(2*k):(3*k)]
[1] 4 5 6
```

If you leave off the parentheses then the sequence will evaluate first then the multiplication:

```
2*k:3*k
[1]  8 12
```

Is the same as

```
(k:3)*2*k
[1]  8 12
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailled comment. I should have it remembered when typing it.